# How to compare date of format "MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a" in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

[image]

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_event WHERE  event_start_date>datetime('Oct 4, 2015 12:00:00 AM')
```

Comment: see DATE_ADDED or DATE_MODIFIED columns from [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html) or BEGIN, END , *_TIME from [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarAlertsColumns.html) or any other android's std date/time column

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the date in the form `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` or in millisecond difference to compare it in the sqlite.

Comment: thanks Sanjeet, But i have saved data in MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a format. Is it not possible to compare data of this format?

Comment: You need to save the date in that format, have a look on sqlite official docs here https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html